# Prevent audio from playing with IBM's Weather Underground temperature notification? (Wunderground)

Tags: notifications, audio, notification-bar, android-13, weather

When IBM's Weather Underground (Wunderground) app is installed, and it is configured to display the current temperature in Android 13's notification bar, the device periodically makes sounds.

If the temperature notification is removed, the annoying sounds cease.  I want to learn how to have the always-present temperature notification without the intrusive sounds.  *I don't want to turn off sounds for notifications of ***all*** apps.*

Comment: Since the introduction of the [notification channel](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels), couldn't the channel's audio be customized to mute/silent/custom empty sound? (I don't use Wunderderground, so I have no idea how it's setup)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you Andrew!  That should do it.  Once deep inside that UI, I selected from the list of sounds one called `None`.  If you write up an answer with info from your comment, I'll upvote and accept it.